# How to create Shortcut to a Web Page in Linux?

Tags: launcher

I am new to Linux and am not a supergeek.  You cannot drag things on to the desktop with Ubuntu 16.04.1 like you can in Windows 7.  I would like to create a shortcut to [this](http://player.streamlicensing.com/2430?l&stream_id=4107).  How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Both Chrome and Firefox will let you drag links to the desktop, where a .desktop file is created. For this page it looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to launcher - How to create Shortcut to a Web Page in Linux? - Ask Ubuntu
Type=Link
URL=http://askubuntu.com/questions/892588/how-to-create-shortcut-to-a-web-page-in-linux
Icon=text-html
```

Answer (score 0):

The icon looks different.  But you can drag and drop web pages and links from Firefox and Chrome just as in Windows.

The Windows link reads the fav.ico icon from the link and displays that icons as the link.  Ubuntu shows a generic icon that looks like a folded page.  It'll have the name of title of the linked page as part of the icon name.

If you right click on the created icon you and click to open it in **Gedit** you'll see details of the page.  In this case the link in your question has these details:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="ua-ua-">
<head>
    <title>Pop Gold Radio</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1030" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,9,edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="Pop Gold Radio Webplayer" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.jplayer292ed.min.js" title="jquery.jplayer292.swf" id="jpjs"></script>
    <script>page=0;</script>
    <script src="js/site.js?4.2.60"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,700" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="skin/base.css?4.2.60" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <meta property="og:title" content="StreamLicensing" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Web player" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="music.radio_station" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://player.streamlicensing.com/2430?l=&stream_id=4107" />



</head>
<body class="skin-">
    <div id="blurdiv"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="jpdivmp3" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
        <div id="jpdivm4a" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
        <div id="jw1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
        <div class="playerbg themebg" style=""></div>
        <div class="player">

            <div class="header titlecolor" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0, .5)"><span class="head_title" style=""><span id="title">Pop Gold Radio</span></span>
            </div>

            <div id="videoad">
                <div>Your station will play momentarily.</div><div id="videoad_v"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="selector" class="themebg col" style="">
                <div class="themebg2">
                    <table cellspacing="0">
                        <tr style="font-size:19px"></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="help" class="last-played">
                <i class="close">&#x2715;</i>               
                <div class="help-inner">
                    <h2 class="titlecolor" id="helptitle">title</h2>
                    <p></p>
                    <div id="privacy"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="last-played" class="last-played">
                <i class="close">&#x2715;</i>
                <div id="songhist"></div>
            </div>



            <div class="player-content">
                                <div class="album-art">
                    <img class="songimg" src="configs/images/noalbum-white.png" />
                </div>

                <ul class="jp-controls">
                    <li><div class="jp-playx iconskin" id="playbtn" onclick="play()" title="Play/Stop"></div></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="jp-no-solution">
                    <div>Trouble Listening?</div>
                    <div><a id="directm3u" href="#" onclick="stop()">Download this m3u playlist to listen.</a></div>
                    Or just wait a little longer. The station may be offline, or you may need to update your browser.
                    <span id="nosoladd"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="song-info notrated">
                    <h1 id="song" class="song titlecolor">
                        <noscript>This player definitely requires JavaScript</noscript>
                    </h1>
                    <h2 id="artist" class="artist"></h2>
                    <!--
                    <div class="rating titlecolor">
                        <i>&#x2605;</i> <i>&#x2605;</i> <i>&#x2605;</i> <i>&#x2605;</i> <i>&#x2606;</i>
                    </div> -->                  
                </div>

                <section class="controls cf">
                    <div class="song-controls">
                        <i class="icon buy-open">&#xe73d;<span class="tooltip">Buy Now</span></i>
                        <a href="#" id="lyrics" target="_blank"><i class="icon lyrics-open">&#x266b;<span class="tooltip">Lyrics</span></i></a>
                        <i class="icon share-open">&#xe73c;<span class="tooltip">Share</span></i>
                        <i class="icon help-open">&#x2753;<span class="tooltip">Help &amp; Privacy</span></i>
                        <div id="vu" class="off"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="player-controls">
                        <span id="current-time">Stopped</span>
                        <i class="fa icon last-played-open">&#xe005;<span class="tooltip">Last Played</span></i>
                        <i class="fa icon mute" id="muteb"><span id="mutetxt">&#x1F50A;</span><span class="tooltip">Mute</span></i>
                        <div id="volumediv">
                            <div id="volume-fill"></div>
                            <div id="volumeknob"></div>
                            <div id="volume-control" class="iconskin"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <div id="debug">
                                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="side-content">
                <div class="banner-right"><iframe id="bnf" src="ad-frame.php?revive&z=3&id=3ac6f81f9fefceffd16a855fa764b74a&srv=adserver.cdnstream.com&refr=120" width="300" height="250" noresize="" scrolling="no" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div>
            </div>

            <div class="lower-content">
                <div class="banner"><iframe id="bnf" src="ad-frame.php?revive&z=15&id=3ac6f81f9fefceffd16a855fa764b74a&srv=adserver.cdnstream.com&refr=120" width="728" height="90" noresize="" scrolling="no" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe></div>

                <div class="lower-side">
                    <div id="linkbuttons">
                        <!--<a class="facebook" href="http://facebook.com/"><i>&#xf30c;</i></a>
                        <a class="twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i>&#xf309;</i></a>-->
                                            </div>
                    <div class="powered-by">Powered by <a target="_blank" href="http://streamlicensing.com/">StreamLicensing.com</a> &amp; <a href="http://last.fm/" target="_blank">last.fm</a><br><img style="margin-top:8px" title="Oi2 Media" src="configs/images/Oi2_28.png" height=28 width=43 /></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="share-overlay overlay">
                <i class="close">&#x2715;</i>
                <section class="overlay-content">
                    <h2 class="song titlecolor">Share This On</h2>
                    <div class="shricons">
                            <a id="afacebook" class="button facebook" href="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=Pop+Gold+Radio&p[summary]=&p[url]=http%3A%2F%2Fplayer.streamlicensing.com%2F2430%3Fl%3D%26stream_id%3D4107&p[images][0]=','sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325'))" tabindex="-1" title="Facebook"><i>&#xf30c;</i></a>
                            <a id="atwitter" class="twitter" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fplayer.streamlicensing.com%2F2430%3Fl%3D%26stream_id%3D4107&text=Listening+to+Pop+Gold+Radio" target="_blank" title="Twitter"><i>&#xf309;</i></a></div>
                </section>
            </div>

            <div class="buy-overlay overlay">
                <i class="close">&#x2715;</i>
                <section class="overlay-content">
                    <h2 class="song titlecolor">Buy This Song</h2>
                    <ul class="buy-icons">
                        <li><a id="buyamz" class="amazon iconskin" href="http://amazon.com" target="_blank"><img src="skin/spacer.gif" /></a></li>
                        <li><a id="buyapp" class="itunes iconskin" href="http://itunes.com" target="_blank"><img src="skin/ajax-loader-white.gif" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>







<script>
slsid = "2430";
autoplay = 1;
playvolume = 0.7;
spotxID = 0;
cc = 1, config = "_streamlicensing";
cfg_synchrobox300 = "", cfg_synchrobox728 = "";
cfg_cc_title = "Pop Gold Radio - %track";
streamcount = 1;
bufferGiveupCount = 18;
var prefer, version = '4.2.60';
mini = 0;
buynowurl = 'http://www.amazon.com/gp/redirect.html?location=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fs%3Fie%3DUTF8%26x%3D0%26ref_%3Dnb_sb_noss%26y%3D0%26field-keywords%3D@%26url%3Dsearch-alias%253Ddigital-music&tag=er0bf-20'; //Replace @ with search term
cfg_itunes_at = "11lLzr";
defaultalbumpic = "configs/images/noalbum-white.png";
cfg_albumbackground = "1";
cfg_albumdisplay = "1";
cfg_staticalbumpic = 0;
cfg_NotASongKeywords = "promo,adwtag,awbreak,ais1,ais3,ais6,adcor,admain,station id,stationid".split(",");
cfg_HideNotASong = "1";
cfg_statictrack = "";
client_IP = "50.75.184.41";
lang = "en";
cfg_albumapi = "lastfm";
debug_ = 0;
prefer = 'H';
streams = [{"format":"v2","host":"70.38.12.44","id":"stream","port":8028}];
master = 0;

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-77407212-1', 'auto');
if('') {
  ga('create', '', 'auto', {'name':'tracker2'});
}
ga('send', 'pageview', '/_streamlicensing');
if('') {
    ga('tracker2.send', 'pageview', '/_streamlicensing');
}
</script>
<!-- Quantcast Tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var qevents = qevents || [];
(function() {
var elem = document.createElement('script');
elem.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://secure" : "http://edge") + ".quantserve.com/quant.js";
elem.async = true;
elem.type = "text/javascript";
var scpt = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
scpt.parentNode.insertBefore(elem, scpt);
})();

_qevents.push({
qacct:"p-tY-2Wgagvfr5J"
});
</script>
<noscript>
<div style="display:none;">
<img src="//pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-tY-2Wgagvfr5J.gif" border="0" height="1" width="1" alt="Quantcast"/>
</div>
</noscript>
<!-- End Quantcast tag --></body>
</html>
```

It's more details and a different type of details than what you see in the Windows link, but it works.

If you douple click on the icon that is created it will take you directly to the page, the same as with Windows.

The answer linked in the question shows methods of creating a *.desktop laucher which can have any number of customized apparence for the actual icon.  But the functionality is basicall the same.